# How to cast to String - updating from from Swift 1.1 to Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, casting, option-type

```
let version:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey(kCFBundleVersionKey) as? String ?? "unknown"
```

I'm getting an error: '(String?, StringLiteralConvertible)' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Comment: Updating to Swift 1.2??? The currently released version is Swift 2.0!

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm going from swift 1.1 -> 1.2... then 1.2 -> 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 7 has the better error message for the problem:

```
error: 'CFString!' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
```

and makes the "Fix-it" suggestion to insert `as String`:

```
let version = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    .objectForInfoDictionaryKey(kCFBundleVersionKey as String)
    as? String ?? "unknown"
```

And this compiles both with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4) and the current
Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var version = "unknown"
if let key = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey(kCFBundleVersionKey) as String {
    version = key
}
```